# Non-anchored history substring search in bash

Tags: bash, command-history, line-editor

There are 2 existing ways to get something like this easily:

- zsh's history-substring-search plugin
- bash's `ctrl+r` mode

The problem with zsh is that it's not on many systems. The problem with bash's implementations is that it requires me to hit ctrl+r first. Also, I know about `history-search-backward` in bash, but it is *anchored to the beginning of the command* and not nearly as powerful.

I'm hoping there is a way to bind the up key in bash to make it:

- copy the currently typed command buffer
- enter `ctrl+r` mode
- paste the currently type command buffer in that mode

and on subsequent presses of the up key

- hit `ctrl+r` (search next previous)

Comment: No, bash's history-search-backward isn't anchored to the beginning of the command. You can search for a substring anywhere in your command lines. The cursor will be placed at the beginning of the match, see for example this search on substring '''mus''' which has found a command called copy_music, and put the cursor at 'm' : https://imgur.com/a/3lsMXam

Comment: @ychaouche history-search-backward is a bind you can make. It only works on the initial substring part of a command. What you show is the Ctrl+R that i describe.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Steven Lu. So if I get this correctly, instead of typing C-r first then your substring, you would like to first type your substring then type have C-r search what you already typed ?

Comment: Yes. That’s right. To have it bound to up arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash 4.4 has `history-substring-search-backward` bindable command that does this.  From the NEWS file:

```
2.  New Features in Readline
<...>
b.  There are new bindable commands to search the history for the string of
    characters between the beginning of the line and the point
    (history-substring-search-forward, history-substring-search-backward)
```

Comment: That’s nice despite it needing to be some time until this new of a bash becomes available on most systems.